# accessing a class within mxml tag

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, namespaces, mxml

I would like to provide my own sortItemRenderer within an AdvancedDataGrid like so:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid sortItemRenderer="MyRenderer"></mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

MyRenderer is a class that I wrote, but Flex doesn't see it and gives "defintion not found" error, because it is not within the mx namespace. What is a clean way to make this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the **fully qualified name** for your renderer : if you class is in package `myPackage.MyRenderer` then `sortItemrenderer="myPackage.MyRenderer"`

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way not to write out the package path and still use the class?

Comment: @Fortress In ActionScript, if your itemRenderer class is in the same package structure as the class that contains your AdvancedDataGrid, then you won't have to fully qualify the class name.  I never tried that in MXML, though.  In AS3 you have to define the classFactory something like this: adg.sortItemRenderer = new ClassFactory(MyRenderer);

Comment: It makes sense to define the classFactory through AS3.